# How to continue on client when heavy server computation is done

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous

This might be a simple problem, but I can't seem to find a good solution right now.

I've got:

- OldApp - a Java application started from the command line (no web front here)
- NewApp - a Java application with a REST api behind Apache

I want **OldApp** to call **NewApp** through its REST api and when **NewApp** is done, **OldApp** should continue.

My problem is that NewApp is doing a lot of stuff that might take a lot of time which in some cases causes a timeout in Apache, and then sends a 502 error to OldApp. The computations continue in NewApp, but OldApp does not know when NewApp is done.

One solution I thought of is fork a thread in NewApp and store some kind of ID for the API request, and return it to OldApp. Then OldApp could poll NewApp to see if the thread is done, and if so - continue. Otherwise - keep polling.

Are there any good design patterns for something like this? Am I complicating things? Any tips on how to think?

Comment: That sounds OK. Model the computation as a Resource, create it, `GET` it until it is finished.

Comment: Here's a simple (and potentially not useful idea): If you have control over the Apache server, you could maybe just increase or turn off the request timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If NewApp is taking a long time, it should immediately return a `202 Accepted`. The response should contain a `Location` header indicating where the user can go to look up the result when it's done, and an estimate of when the request will be done.

OldApp should wait until the estimate time is reached, then submit a new GET call to the location. The response from that GET will either be the expected data, or an entity with a new estimated time. OldApp can then try again at the later time, repeating until the expected data is available.

So The conversation might look like:

```
POST /widgets
response:
202 Accepted
Location: "http://server/v1/widgets/12345"
{
    "estimatedAvailableAt": "<whenever>"
}
```

.

```
GET /widgets/12345
response:
200 OK
Location: "http://server/v1/widgets/12345"
{
    "estimatedAvailableAt": "<wheneverElse>"
}
```

.

```
GET /widgets/12345
response:
200 OK
Location: "http://server/v1/widgets/12345"
{
    "myProperty": "myValue",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I'm just curious on how and when to use different HTTP status codes. In your example, during the first GET, when we get a new estimated time - you return a 200 OK. But we do not have a result yet. Is it logical to still use 200 OK?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. The HTTP status code applies to the success or failure of the call itself, not the code running under the call. They request the resource, you successfully return it. The resource happens to say "try back later", but they asked for and received it successfully. If there were a 267 Not Done Yet response, that might be better, but there isn't one. This is the best way I've seen to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what people are doing with REST now. Because there no way to connect from server to client, client just polls very often. There also some improved method called "long polling", when connection between client and server has big timeout, and server send information back to connected client when it becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

The question is on java and servlets ... So I would suggest looking at Servlet 3.0 asynchronous support.

Talking from a design perspective, you would need to return a 202 accepted with an Id and an URL to the job. The oldApp needs to check for the result of the operation using the URL.

The thread that you fork on the server needs to implement the Callable interface. I would also recommend using a thread pool for this. The GET url for the Job that was forked can check the Future object status and return it to the user.